# Microservices UI Frontend with Java and ReactJS Server Side Rendering

Tags: java, reactjs, microservices, server-side-rendering

My current design is to have clients connect to my (Java) Web API Gateway using a browser, the Web API Gateway will call each (Java) microservice to get their JSON data and return it to the UI component that made the request on the client.

The only client side rendering will be from each ReactJS UI component for recurring requests to the gateway.

On the server side the full HTML view will be rendered prior to being sent back to the client.

```
Client browser

     ▼ (Request Dashboard View)

Web API Gateway

     ▼ (Request microservice JSON data)

Microservice A JSON Data
Microservice B JSON Data
Microservice C JSON Data
Microservice D JSON Data

     ▼ (Return JSON Data to gateway)

Web API Gateway

     ▼ (Render HTML and return to Client)

Client browser

     ▼ (ReactJS UI Components request data from API Gateway)
```

This is where it gets unclear, would it be best to have each UI component communicate with the Web API Gateway or the parent Microservice it came from to get data?

Considerations

- Having the UI components talk to the Web API Gateway seems reasonable but will couple the microservices to the gateway, meaning to expose a new API on the microservice the gateway will also need to be updated.
- Having the UI components talk directly to its Microservice for data removes the need to also update the Web API Gateway, keeping them less coupled. But this then exposes the Microservice to external calls from the client browser.

Design Decisions

- Having the UI components within the API gateways creates a UI monolith as opposed to having each microservice responsible for its own UI component. Using the monolithic approach simplifies the solution and also avoids the complexities of having to aggregate each microservices UI component when the client requests a particular view.

Tools:

- Java
- Nashorn
- Dropwizard
- ReactJS
- Gradle
- Webpack
- NodeJS
- NPM

**How do I aggregate multiple microservice ui components on the Web API Gateway using Java and ReactJS then serve this pre-rendered HTML data along with the JavaScript application to the client?**

**Helpful References:**

- Server side rendering with Java 8 and Nashhorn http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/02/16/isomorphic-react-webapps-on-the-jvm/

Comment: You load the data as json from each microservice

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Yes but I'm looking for guidance on how the process should be carried out. I've updated the question.

Comment: With server side rendering?

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU question updated.

Comment: I still don't understand if you need server side rendering or not

Comment: The React component will be in JavaScript on the Microservice, the javascript can be returned to the Gateway then aggregated with the other components to form the full view. There is no need to return the React component as JSON to the gateway. Or am I wrong? I may need server side rendering at the gateway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141669/discussion-between-mortond-and-constantin-galbenu).

Comment: Is my answer the solution? Thanks!

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Sorry no, I've updated the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**

How to aggregate ReactJS UI components during server side rendering on the Web API gateway.

**Solution**

Use a templating framework like [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) to inject the rendered HTML output of each ReactJS component server side, then serve this HTML back to the client.

Github repo https://github.com/damorton/dropwizardheroku-webgateway

**Server Side**

The solution I implemented on the Web API gateway first requested the JSON data from the microservice, then rendered the ReactJS component while injecting the JSON data from the microservice as `Props`. Once I had the fully rendered ReactJS component with data as a HTML string I used Mustache templating to inject the fully rendered ReactJS component HTML into the Mustache template, then returned this to the client.

**WebGatewayResource.java**

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public IndexView index() throws IOException {

    // Get events json data from Events microservice
    ApiResponse events = getEventsJsonData();

    // Render the Events component and pass in props
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Object> eventsProps = (List<Object>) events.getList();
    String eventsComponent = this.nashornController.renderReactJsComponent(kEventsUiComponentRenderServerFunction, eventsProps);

    IndexView index = new IndexView(eventsComponent);
    return index;
}
```

*Note:* Dropwizard performs alot of magic around Mustache templating so all that was needed was to create an `index.mustache` file and reference this when constructing the `IndexView` class. Returning this `View` to the client tells Dropwizard to render the view and return the HTML.

**index.mustache**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Dropwizard Heroku Event Service</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react-dom-server.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.16.1/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Events</h1>
  <div id="events">{{{eventsComponent}}}</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Client side**

On the client side, to fix an issue with the client and server side rendered HTML being different due to the props for the ReactJS components not being available when the component was mounted initially, a javascript function is called when the page loads to request the JSON data from the gateway.

**client.js**

```
var loadEventsFromServer = function(eventsUrl) {
    axios.get(eventsUrl).then(function(res) {
        var data = res.data.list;       
        renderClientEvents(data);
    });
};

loadEventsFromServer('https://domain.webapigateway.com/events');
```

**ReactJS**

The client side HTML is not re-rendered when the component is mounted, React is aware of the already existing HTML from the server side render and only adds the event listeners for each component when it mounts. This allows React to update its components individually, and also takes advantage of server side rendering.

Answer (score 3):

So, a `React component` needs two things: the `JavaScript` source code and the data.

The JavaScript source code can be provided by a CDN.

The data must be provided by the Microservices.

If you don't want server side rendering, then the skeleton index.html file along with the `JS` files are provided by a CDN.

If you need server side rendering (for SEO purposes, for example) then the API gateway (or another Web server) will render the components using `NodeJS` by requesting their source code from the CDN and their data from the microservices then return the full `HTML` to the browser.

On the client side, `React` will continue to load other data from the right microservice as `JSON` using the `API gateway`.

Comment: This is great info, helped alot, but I'm using Java not NodeJS, and I believe the ReactJS UI components should access only the Web API Gateway and not the Microservice it came from.

Comment: @mortond It does not matter whether you use Java or NodeJS for the microservices. You could use *any stack* and the components wouldn't care. The idea is that the components *download* only `JSON` data from the microservices, using the `API Gateway` or not. `NodeJS` is used only if you need server side rendering.

Comment: I understand that it dosent matter how the microservice is implemeted, but I'm using Java/Dropwizard. My question is about server side rendering using a stack of Java/ReactJS.

Comment: You situation is complicated because you keep the source code of the component in the microservice. You should keep them all in one location, i.e. a webserver with `NodeJS` installed and to render them from that webserver as a `Single page application`.

Comment: And you should use Java only to generate the `JSON` dynamic content

Comment: Having all of the UI components in one place creates a `Front End Monolith`, whereas I want to adhere to the Microservice architecture as much as possible by keeping each microservice self contained. I will add that this is an exercise in learning for me more so than a production solution, there are obviously pros and cons to each approach. Thanks for your help so far by the way! :thumbs_up:

Comment: Monoliths are not bad if they are modular and React kinda makes you to modularize. Anyway, be careful to not mix the concerns, rendering data and generating data so you put too much responsibility to the microservice. Even if you continue with your architecture be sure that you keep the two concern separated.

Comment: I've come to the realisation that a UI monolith is an easier goal to achieve if learning how all of this works initially. The problem I ran into was that I needed to provide the event handlers to the client browser along with the per rendered html for the React components. I was unaware that the actual UI component used for server side rendering is also needed to run in the client browser for dynamic updating. The difficult part would be to load each component from each microservice and serve both the rendered html AND each components event handlers, i.e. in a `bundle.js`

Comment: Yes. This is why I recommended them to be stored on the central/Gateway server.