# Merge Microservice Frontends Together

Tags: microservices

I want to merge serveral frontend parts of different microservices together to an whole website. My idea behind this was to have a **frontend**, **backend** and **database** part in each microservice.

I already familiar with microservices but I never used them to create a website, especially the frontend part.
Are there any articles about that or something like tutorials or maybe someone at stackoverflow can explain me more in depth how or with which "tool" I could put the microservices together.

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396744/microservices-ui-frontend-with-java-and-reactjs-server-side-rendering

Comment: What microservices you have and what do you want to obtain in the end?

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU the other question didn't really help.

atm I only have a concept of what I want to accomplish. For e.g. I want to have a seperate microservice for my user profiles, search bar and a news feed (similar to that what facebook uses to display post) but I dont want to have all that in a monolytic frontend part where all the single microservices just send the data to, but have it in each microservice and then have them all "rendered" together so that it still seems that it is an monolytic frontend part.

Comment: Ok, then you can't have a single page application, for example, do you?

Comment: correct, I guess. Every microservice should be as independent as possible.

Comment: So, you have two options: load all the `widgets` from each microservices on the client (with JavaScript) or compose the `widgets` on the server (using Server side rendering - PHP, Java,C#) ;a `widget` contains the HTML code

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want to do but in essence that's not what microservices are about as far as I understand. It's the service bit in the name that makes a difference. When you assemble a front end, a backend and a db together you're more or less building a complete application. You gain much more freedom in changing the UI by decoupling it.

Lars

Comment: Hi Lars, but I'll still have the problem that my whole frontend will be down while I deploy new features e.g. for my user profiles right?
I guess I found kinda solution using a mix of esi and csi,this will be somehow the way to go since I want my teams to work independently of each other on their services/application so that no team really rely on each other.